# Get back my old raspbian desktop from an accidental switch to LXDE

Tags: debian, raspbian, desktop-environment, lxde

So, I was tinkering around on my laptop, which has the raspbian for desktop (Debian with the raspbian desktop environment) and accidentally double clicked on the file saying "LXDE" and it changed my desktop environment to LXDE.
How do I go back to my old desktop?

Comment: Is there a file in the same area named xfce or mate? Also did you try rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

At reboot time, underneath the login name field, you will now see a choice of Desktops; choose the PIXEL, *Pi Improved X-Window Environment, Lightweight*, the one which isn't LXDE.